# How to parse a complicated csv file in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have been struggling with the parsing of a complicated *.csv file as shown below. It has 6 lines, however, all colum headers, ids, field values are listed in single rows separated with commas. Most of the headers have spaces and units "(in)" which need to be taken as it is.

***Example file:***

```
    Version,1.1,1198    
    Dimension Unit,in,1000.000000
    Angle Unit,°,17.095780
    Measurement Names,Body height (in),Head height (in),Neck height (mm),Distance neck to buttock (in),Distance neck-knee (in)
    Measurement IDs,0010,0020,0030,0040,0050
    C:\Data\new.csv,796,,398,212
```

***What I want is:***

1. skip the first 3 lines
2. Make 3 colums with the header:

   - "Measurement Names" (taken from line #4),
   - "Measurement IDs" (taken from line #5) and
   - "C:\Data\new.csv" (last line)
3. seperate all fields at the commas and transpose them into the right colum
4. handle some empty field values

***After parsing it correctly it should be arranged like:***

```
    Measurement Names             Measurement IDs  C:\Data\new.csv 
    Body height (in)              0010             796  
    Head height (in)              0020
    Neck height (in)              0030             398
    Distance neck to buttock (in) 0040             212
    Distance neck-knee (in)       0050
```

I've tried read.csv, read.table but the only thing that read in successfully was readLines. However, it did not skip the first 3 lines even though this option was given. Also, it did not matter what encoding. 
Assuming that

```r
data <- "C:\\Temp\\test.csv"
filename <- file(data,open="r")

Zeile <-readLines(filename,
                  skip=3,
                  #warn=FALSE,
                  encoding = 'utf-16-be'
                  )
Zeile <- strsplit(Zeile, ",") # here I try to split 
for (i in 1:length(Zeile)){
  print(Zeile[i])
}
close(filename)
```

The result look like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Version" "1.1"     "1198\t"  

[[1]]
[1] "Length Unit" "mm"          "1000.000000"

[[1]]
[1] "Angle Unit" "Â°"         "57.295780" 

[[1]]
[1] "Measurement Names"             "Body height (mm)"              "Head height (mm)"             
[4] "Neck height (mm)"              "Distance neck to buttock (mm)" "Distance neck-knee (mm)"      

[[1]]
[1] "Measurement IDs" "0010"            "0020"            "0030"            "0040"           
[6] "0050"           

[[1]]
[1] "C:\\Data\\new.csv" "796"               ""                  "398"               "212"              

[[1]]
character(0)
```

There are quotes and the field values are not aligned unter the correct colum.

***How do I get the expected result into a data frame for further processing ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
read.csv("path/your_file.csv", sep = ",", skip = 3, colClasses = "character") %>% 
   gather(Measurement_Names, v, -Measurement.Names) %>% 
   spread(Measurement.Names, v)
             Measurement_Names  C:\\Data\\new.csv Measurement IDs
1              Body.height..mm.               796            0010
2       Distance.neck.knee..mm.                              0050
3 Distance.neck.to.buttock..mm.               212            0040
4              Head.height..mm.                              0020
5              Neck.height..mm.               398            0030
```

Comment: just for sake of completeness, uses library `tidyr`

Comment: @R.S. just forgotten to include the required package. Thanks

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm. What does %>% do in that code ?

Answer (score 1):

it's not R, but I think it could be useful. I'm using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and csvtk (https://bioinf.shenwei.me/csvtk/).

Running

```
tail -n +4 input_01.csv | mlr --nidx --fs "," cat -n  then unsparsify | csvtk transpose | tail -n +2
```

you will have

```
Measurement Names,Measurement IDs,C:\Data\new.csv
Body height (mm),0010,796
Head height (mm),0020,
Neck height (mm),0030,398
Distance neck to buttock (mm),0040,212
Distance neck-knee (mm),0050,
```

Or pretty printed running

```
tail -n +4 input_01.csv | mlr --nidx --fs "," cat -n  then unsparsify | csvtk transpose | tail -n +2 | mlr --c2p cat
```

to have

```
Measurement Names             Measurement IDs C:\Data\new.csv
Body height (mm)              0010            796
Head height (mm)              0020            -
Neck height (mm)              0030            398
Distance neck to buttock (mm) 0040            212
Distance neck-knee (mm)       0050            -
```